# Binding selectize with aurelia

Tags: selectize.js, aurelia

I am trying to use selectize with aurelia.io
I have created template shop.html

```
<template>
    <input ref="content" type="text" value.two-way="shops" >
</template
```

and in my **class shop** with adnotation **@customElement('shop')** I 
am trying to bind *selectize.js* to **@bindable shops**

```
attached() {  
    var s = $(this.content).selectize({
        delimiter: ',',
        persist: false,      
        create: function(input) {
            return {
                value: input,
                text: input
            }
        }         
    });}
```

I am using this custom element with template books, like this:

```
<shop shops.two-way="selected.data.bookshops" ></shop>
```

Two way data binding is not working as I expected.
Selectize value is only updated for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the need to capture selectize's change event in my custom element and propagate it to the original select input, in order for Aurelia's data binding to work.  Add a change handler on the selectize to propagate the event.

```
    // init selectize
    this.sel = el.selectize(opts)[0]; // first element

    // on change after setting initial value
    this.sel.selectize.on('change', () => {
        // no event param passed in
        console.log(`Selectize change event`);
        // dispatch to raw select within the custom element for data binding trigger
        // bubble it up to custom event in case change event is handled
        let notice = new Event('change', {bubbles: true});
        $(el)[0].dispatchEvent(notice);
    });
```

By bubbling up the change event, this will also allow you to add an change.delegate handler on your custom element when it is used in a view.

```
    <selectize ... change.delegate='changeHandler()'>
```

Comment: Please don't post links to gist, put the code into your answer. Please see [answer]

Comment: That isn't true. From your FAQ: "Links to external resources are encouraged..." as long as context is provided.   However I edited my answer as my approach has slightly changed over what was in that original gist.

Comment: [Please read this meta question as it directly addresses your point](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326744/github-links-as-answers/326745#326745)

Answer (score 0):

You have to install *selectize* which depends on *sifter*, *microplugin* and *jquery*

```
jspm jquery
jspm install selectize
jspm install sifter
jspm install microplugin
```

Then you can import and use it

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import selectize  from 'selectize';
```

Comment: I have done it. The problem is with binding selectize to object. I wanna achive two-ways data-binding on selectize input.